# Attempting (and failing) to scrape financial data from google finance using python beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new and having trouble with this, it would be great if someone could show me exactly where I am going wrong (rather than just a solution).

So far it is fairly self-explanatory...

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.google.co.uk/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&fstype=ii&ei=_dupU6DgFMTGwAPR6YHQDA'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

The data I am looking is for easy to locate:

```
soup.find.all("tr",{"class":"hilite"})
```

inputting in the console turns out all the right info

Where I am stuck is how to work this into a for loop (I am new-ish to programming).

I know my headers are `1td class =lft lm bld` and my data is `td class = rbld` but I really have no idea how to get this into arrays. Any help in understanding the concepts behind this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest example would iterate over `tr` tags and use `find_all()` to get `td` tags for every row:

```
for row in soup.find_all("tr", {'class': "hilite"}):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        print cell.text
    print "-----"
```

Prints:

```
Total Revenue

45,646.00
57,594.00
37,472.00
35,323.00
43,603.00
-----
Gross Profit

17,947.00
...
```